# How did Ant Man breathe when he shrank down to sub-atomic level?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

Oxygen molecules would be bigger than him, and they therefore wouldn't be able to fit into his tiny lungs to have oxygen available for cellular respiration, and thence the energy to live. He was at a sub-atomic size for quite a while, and I'm not sure that the suit supplies him with oxygen. An atom is mainly empty space...

What really sparked my interest is when Hank Pym (in the end) thinks that his wife could still be alive - it is plausible that since physics at the sub-atomic level is different than how we experience it in every day life. But for her, time will be passing at the same rate as normal. If Pym could find her, his time experience would be different, and she would experience a long time at sub-atomic size with her oxygen levels probably depleted (present only minimally in small air spaces in her suit), and would suffocate.

How is what Pym believes justifiable, and how could Ant Man have spent so long in a sub-atomic state and still be alive ?

Comment: It's only really justifiable if you don't think about it too hard.

Comment: But we have to think hard about it since intellectual characters in Marvel utilize so many real world theories in their dialog.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly how long Scott was at sub atomic size, and I get the impression time passes differently on the sub atomic level. It's possible that there was some air left in the suite or air still in his lungs and since time is different he was able to survive for the length of the scene. Had he been there longer it's possible he would have suffocated.

Comment: There's is absolutely nothing real-world about any of the science in Ant-Man :\

Comment: Yes there is, you just have to look for how its plausible in real world science somehow it is plausible and theoretically possible, you just have to tackle it one step at a time and not allowing to over whelm where we are driven to the point were we resort to condemning it impossible.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're into quack physics :)

Comment: There was mention in an interview (I believe with Kevin Feige) indicating that Dr Strange's powers were going to be related to the Quantum Realm, and not "mystical" as in the comics. It's possible that this Quantum Realm is some sort of alternate dimension, and not just the space "between the molecules".

Comment: @RERT588, The problem with the shrinking in Ant-Man is that it relies on reducing the space between particles in atoms. That said, you are still a sum of the atoms that make you, so no matter how much space you remove, the nucleus of a hydrogen atom will remain the same size as the nucleus of another hydrogen atom. Therefore, Ant-Man could only get as small as the sum of all the protons, neutrons and electrons that made him up, which would be substantially larger than a single atom by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Maybe but they the atoms were depicted in Ant Man and then we saw purple threads. This could be the alluding to String theory which shows that more than three dimensions exist.

Comment: @rert588, That may be what they were alluding to, yes, but in string theory the strings are infinitesimally small, but when it comes to the universes that they encompass, they become infinitely large. Regardless, my point still stands in regards to the shrinking. You cannot shrink something made of atoms smaller than an atom.

Comment: @USFBS I don't see your point. I don't dispute the fact that the sum of atoms remains constant.

Comment: Maybe, but long ago people thought they couldn't split the atom and today we can and do.

Comment: There are also physics questions that bear on the nature of nuclei and the baryons themselves, vis a vis, whether the scale of the fundamental particles can be modified as well. But none of that changes the problem being addressed here, which is that your lungs can't breathe in O2 when they nucleus is the reference size of a basketball (or a planet).

Comment: @rert588, Well, because the idea that Ant-Man could even get that small is ludicrous, any rules that were not introduced by the writers can be thrown out. Therefore, the justification for Ant-Man not dying is because it meshes with the made-up physics that the writers created for the movie.

Comment: Pretty sure that it was said at some point that time works differently in the quantum realm though I don't have an exact quote to hand. I certainly half expected him to come back with Pym's wife having not aged at all.

Comment: @Chris I thought that too, until I remembered that even though they're shrinking, they're still in the same spot where they shrunk. Once Antman figured out how to move, it probably would have still taken him years just to get out of Yellowjacket's suit, and centuries to leave his daughter's bedroom. Considering Pym's wife seemed to disappear somewhere over the ocean, there's no chance he could have found her

Comment: @childcat15: Yeah, though if you can handwave time doesn't exist there I'm sure handwaving distance meaning something different would be pretty easy. As it is it didn't happen so we don't need to speculate about it (yet?). :)

Comment: He used a Suspension of Dibelief generator :-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is only briefly touched on in this movie, but from comments made by Marvel's Kevin Feige, we'll be seeing a lot more of the "Quantum Realm" in future movies. At the moment, we're working on the assumption that this is actually the MCU equivalent of the Microverse, which appears in many of the Fantastic Four and Ant-Man comic storylines.

The Microverse is not just the "smallest level" of our universe: it's a different place, with different rules, that can only be reached by shrinking down to quantum-level sizes in our universe. Once there, however, things exist "normally", including whole civilizations, even with their own heroes:

[image]

At this point, we can only assume Scott ended up in something analogous to the Microverse, and that it allowed him to exist and stay alive until he could grow himself back into our universe.

Comment: I like your answer.

Comment: really? someone downvoted my awesome picture?

Comment: I came here to post an answer about the microverse and how it is already marvel comics canon the possibility to shrink to sub atomic, but Michael beat me.

Comment: But the Microverse isn't a microscopic universe. It is a sub-dimensional/near parallel realm only accessible by entities who can shrink to the sub-atomic sizes necessary to access it.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield they must have been disappointed with the lack of [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/257485)

Comment: This corroborated here: http://www.wired.com/2015/07/ant-man-shrinks-by-stretching-into-other-dimensions/

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That's not at all the same thing. That article is doing something very silly, and trying to apply speculative advanced quantum physics to a made-up movie physics and hoping for the best :\

Answer (score 38):

#### In the movie, Ant-Man's costume is supposedly self-contained and shrinks the oxygen needed along with the miniature hero -- hence the closed-face helmet. Shrinking the oxygen molecules would be for the scale of reduction, so that when Ant-Man shrank to sizes where he would clearly no longer be able to interact with oxygen gas due to scale, he would still have an air supply no matter how small he became.

[image]

- In an interview featured in the latest issue of Empire, costume designers Sammy Sheldon and Ivo Coveney discuss the loosely-based logistics behind the Ant-Man suit worn by Rudd’s Scott Lang.
- **Adhering to realism in one sense, the suit is designed to be self-contained, since oxygen molecules would be too large to breathe for a shrunken superhero.** (emphasis added)

> However, that aspect also takes form with two crucial cables jutting out the side of his helmet. As Coveney comments:
>
> "We had a long discussion about the two cables going into his helmet.
> They're a massive weakness - Yellowjacket could just rip them off and
> he's dead. But, in the end, it just looks cooler with them on."
>
> "Ant-Man's Costume Has One Massive Flaw." Cinemablend.com. N.p. Web. 5 Aug. 2015. http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Ant-Man-Costume-Has-One-Massive-Flaw-71656.html

Comment: It looks as tough he is breathing through a filter. Could you justify that Pym's wife could still be alive.

Comment: Ugh. Did the costume designers really say that "oxygen molecules would be too large to breathe for a shrunken superhero", or did cinemablend *infer* that? What do they think ants breathe?

Comment: They would be, not because the molecules are inherently too large, but because our lungs are designed for O2 to be a particular size, and they would be larger. If you shrunk an ant, it would have the same problem.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield question states "subatomic level" on title, so in the context of this SE Q&A, yes, oxygen molecules are too big.

Comment: @Mindwin I don't see your point. I specifically asked if the *costume designers* actually said that. I doubt the people working on Ant-Man were trying to answer this question...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield dunno.